# Lost iCloud data, how can I get Apple Support to care?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud

Guess I'm just looking for advice / if this has happened to anyone else. I recently upgraded from iPhone X to 11 and, in the process, my entire Apple Music Library disappeared. I raised it with support and they've given nothing but stupid assertions like

> what happened is that the option to “overwrite" your iCloud Music
>   Library was chosen, as opposed to “Merge” when setting it up.

There's no evidence and I can say to a high degree of certainty that I was never given this option. They've also said it's because I travelled abroad with my phone.
I know that there are laws surrounding loss of cloud data, but it seems like a long and expensive way to move forward. I guess I was just expecting more than a "shove off" from Apple Support over what I can only assume was / is a bug.

Comment: Have you changed your iTunes/iCloud/App Store region?

Comment: yes but 6 months ago, I'd already added devices in that time which kept my library

Comment: Can you access iCloud Music Library on another device to see if it's still there (and just not on the 11)?

Comment: I could on both an iPad and other iPhone but they’ve all disappeared from there to